# iMac version 10.8.5 keychain isn't working and I didn't send the backup keychain to Apple

Tags: macos, mac, passwords, osx-mountain-lion, keychain

`How can we get into the computer without the usernames and passwords?What if there's an administration reset/backup keychain set and I can't remember what that is.  I've tried every old password and the password hint isn't matching my answer (fantasy-place+year = Legoland80).  Can I reset my computer completely?  How do I go about doing that?  How do I avoid that?  I didn't send the key to apple like I should have, but took a screenshot with my computer, which is now not accessible anymore.  I tried some other suggestions like deleting keychains, but I can delete all of them EXCEPT the one that needs to be deleted.  I'm to the point where I can't even install apps or burn discs anymore.  HELP!!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Your question seems to be a little all over the place. I would suggest reviewing it so it's clear and concise what you are asking - I think I counted 6 total which will make it hard to answer you can find more information on asking good questions here [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Made perfect sense to me. I had to do this when my daughter forgot her password.

Go here:

http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/10/forgot-mac-password-how-to-reset-mac-password/

You can reset the password on your Mac without a boot disk.